# I can ssh from host1 into host2, but on host 2 I seem to have no connectivity to the network (no ping, no dns, nothing works)

Tags: networking, routing, connection

I assume it's related to a bad configuration on host 2 because a 3rd host plugged into 2'socket works fine. This is all wired in the same subnet with a switch in between.

'ping' produces 100% packet loss.

'arp -a' sees systems in the neigborhood with the correct IP and MAC address, but no hostname and sometimes things like:

`? (192.168.4.99) at <incomplete> on eth0`

route commands produce reasonable results (the same results on host 1 and 2, except for ip addresses(2) vs, hostnames (1)) and host 2 needs about 20s to produce the result vs. host 1 with almost no delay.

The ssh communication works fine - some data packets find their way back to host 1.

There is no firewall involved (rPi-s running raspian)

- Host 1: Linux megapi 4.9.80-v7+ #1098 SMP Fri Mar 9 19:11:42 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
- Host 2: Linux pumpi 4.19.97+ #1294 Thu Jan 30 13:10:54 GMT 2020 armv6l GNU/Linux

Where start debugging? This is a headless system embedded deep inside other hardware. Even swapping the SD card would be rather inconvenient. (poor choice of mine)

```
$ ip r
default via 192.168.4.1 dev enxb827eb69e3a9 proto dhcp src 192.168.4.50 metric 202<P> 192.168.4.0/24 dev enxb827eb69e3a9 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.4.50 =metric 202
```

`iptables-save` does not produce any output

Comment: Please add output of `ip r` and `iptables-save` to your question.

Comment: $ ip r<br/>
default via 192.168.4.1 dev enxb827eb69e3a9 proto dhcp src 192.168.4.50 metric 202<P>

192.168.4.0/24 dev enxb827eb69e3a9 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.4.50 =metric 202

iptables-save does not produce any output

Comment: (excuse the poor formating, but I could not figure how to create line breaks within the allowed  5min edit period.)

Comment: You can edit the question and add the output as a code block.